# Django translations not getting translated on dictionary values

Tags: python, django

I'm using a ordered dict like this

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

'alumni': OrderedDict([
    ('profession', {
        'name': _('Occupation'),
        'field': 'profession',
        'key': 'profession',
        'type': 'text'
    })])
```

And I've the translation on the file like

```
msgid "Occupation"
msgstr "Meslek"
```

But the transaltion is not working.

I'd tried it like this on shell and it seems to be working.

```
In [1]: from django.utils import translation
In [2]: translation.activate('tr')
In [3]: translation.gettext('Occupation')
Out[3]: 'Meslek'
```

All other translations are working fine, Issue is only with the ones defined on dict.

Comment: Try to use `ugettext_lazy` instead of `ugettext`

Comment: I have the same problem, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to find the solution in this way

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
 
TITLES = {
        1: _('Title One'),
        2: _('Title Two'),
        3: _('Title Three'),
    }

_(str(TITLES[1]))
```